# Dynamic filtering based on selected Layer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, polygon, point-in-polygon, intersect

I am not sure this is even possible, I have about 38 geographical polygon layers showing areas of the UK, I also have a query (point layer) that shows all of the offices around the uk. What I am attempting to do is if I select layer 1 that only the offices that intersect with displayed polygons are show. Then if I display an additional layer or change the displayed layer the shown points change accordingly.
Image one shows offices outside and inside the layer polygons,
[image: Area One]
Image two I have switch the polygon layers but I want only the intersecting offices to show.[image: Neighboring area two]
I could do this with having 38 separate attribute queries but that seems an excessive amount of work.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.1.

Comment: Do you have a query to show/hide some polygons? You should reuse it to show/hide points the same way. Copy the field used in the polygon query  to the points' attribute table using Spatial Join, if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no, the show/hide  option I am using is the tick box in the table of contents pane. I tried using a spatial join but could not get it to work it just showed the entire data-set every-time

Comment: So each polygon is in a separate feature class?

Comment: Not all they are in clusters of 4 or 5